# Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL instagram access token api

Tags: java, api, access-token, instagram-api, urlconnection

I am trying to get access token using access token api of instagram after obtaining authorization code .

I am using following code below to get access token from access token url api.

httpurl argument:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Insta_SMI_M1/auth&code=CODE
```

Code

```
     public String getAccessToken(String httpurl){
        try {
                URL url = new URL(httpurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                BufferedReader  rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String result="";
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result+=line;
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                return result;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e.toString());
               }
        return "Hello";
    }
```

It giving me following Error

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=cf07d1a2c69940e59420b6db4c936f4a&client_secret=fb0a975ca2024a1592459308df5ead47&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Insta_SMI_M1/auth&code=b520236c3ceb4f40a3d4c31aa0b3ff84
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at mvc.InstaController.getAccessToken(InstaController.java:179)
at mvc.InstaController.getAuthCode(InstaController.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I went through the this [405 response code instagram access token api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687122/java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-405-for-url) , still no luck.

Any help would greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was curl is doing POST request but my code was doing GET request.

Below is the code doing post request.

```
 public String accessTkn (String code)
 {
     try {

         HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");

         // Request parameters and other properties.
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", Constants.CLIENT_ID));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", Constants.CLIENT_SECRET));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri",  Constants.REDIRECT_URI_AUTH));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code",  code));


         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

         //Execute and get the response.
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         System.out.println("entity "+ entity.getContent());

         if (entity != null) {
             InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
             try {

                return (getStringfromStream(instream));
                 // do something useful
             } finally {
                 instream.close();
             }
         }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Abhay";

 }
```